# Conversion miles to km

Tags: java, for-loop

I need to write a program that displays conversion from miles to km and km to miles in one 'for' loop.It should be displayed in one line. Miles are incremented by 1 from 1 till 10, km are incremented by 5 from 20 to 65. The error says: "variable convertedmls might not have been initialized"

```
    int kms;
    int miles;
    double convertedkms;
    double convertedmls;

    System.out.println("Miles  Kilometers | Kilometers  Miles");

    for (kms = 20;kms <= 65;kms = kms + 5)
        convertedmls = kms / 1.609;
    for (miles = 1;miles <= 10; miles= miles +1){
        convertedkms = miles * 1.609;
        System.out.printf("%,.f      %,.3f      %,.f     %,.3f%n", miles, convertedkms, kms, convertedmls);;         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`double convertedkms=0;
double convertedmls=0;`

Initialize the variable as above then your problem will be solved. Then look into logic.
Also, keep the print statement out side the for loop.
 `System.out.printf("%,.f %,.3f %,.f %,.3f%n", miles, convertedkms, kms, convertedmls);;`

Comment: This would be a better answer if it explained the reason for your fix.